# DownloadManager and SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, android-download-manager

I'm getting:

```
W/DownloadManager﹕ Aborting request for download 29: 
while trying to execute request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: 
Trust anchor for certification path not found. FinalStatus = 194
```

I have bought certificate. I have *.bks file inside /res/raw. What is the way to pass it to `DownloadManager`? I had no problem with OkHttpClient and Volley... but I don't know how it should be done with DownloadManager.

Comment: Add certificate to trust zone.

Comment: @PankajKumar thanks, can you direct me, where that zone is?

Comment: Read http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html this will help you.